# Modify the time zone and character set of the docker image mysql in file mode

Tags: mysql

Default configuration of mysql

```
mysql> show variables like'%time_zone';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | UTC    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
```

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                         |
| character_set_connection | latin1                         |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | latin1                         |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to change the time zone to East 8 and the character set to utf-8 to solve the problem of Chinese garbled characters

Answer (score 1):

**Permanently modify the timezone of mysql in a Docker container**

Valid for mysql docker image 5.7 ~ latest

Enter the docker image that has run successfully

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

View the database time zone configuration:

```
show variables like'%time_zone';
```

View database time zone results:

```
mysql> show variables like "%time_zone";
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | UTC    |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
```

View the database character set configuration:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
```

View database character set results:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                         |
| character_set_connection | latin1                         |
| character_set_database   | latin1                         |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | latin1                         |
| character_set_server     | latin1                         |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Upgrade the apt package management tool (reason: you cannot download vim without upgrading)

```
apt-get update
```

Download vim after apt upgrade is complete

```
apt-get install vim
```

If vim modifies the docker.cnf or mysqld.cnf image file, it will take effect. You can modify any one of them.

```
vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
```

OR：

```
vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

The default display in the file (the following are all taking docker.cnf as an example):

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

Add time zone configuration: Dongba District (China)

```
[mysqld]
default-time_zone = '+8:00'
```

Increase database server utf8 character set configuration

```
[mysqld]
character_set_server=utf8
```

Increase database client utf8 character set configuration

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

After the addition is completed, it will be displayed as:

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
default-time_zone = '+8:00'
character_set_server=utf8

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

After the configuration is saved, restart the database (valid for 5.7)

```
service mysql restart
```

**It is recommended to exit the container and restart the container directly (because you still need to start the image after restarting mysql, it is better to exit the container and restart the image directly)

```
docker restart mysql
```

Enter docker image mysql again to see if the modification is successful

Time zone view:

```
show variables like "%time_zone";
```

time zone view results：

```
mysql> show variables like "%time_zone";
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | UTC    |
| time_zone        | +08:00 |
+------------------+--------+
```

Character set view：

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
```

Character set view result：

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think it's permanent, because you modifying files inside container, not on volume, recreating the container will drop your changes